# How to integrate limelight in vim?

Tags: vim, vi, vim-plugin

I had been trying to customize my _vimrc using https://github.com/amix/vimrc
Then I came across https://github.com/junegunn/limelight.vim and would want to add it.

I blindly copied the configuration code (that was given in the Readme) in the _vimrc but it didn't help.

Can someone explain how exactly to do this?

I am using GVim and rest of the plugins are working fine.

Comment: Did you try the `:Limelight0.8` command in Vim? Do you have the "Awesome" version of amix's vimrc? That's the one that includes plug-ins...

Comment: @filbranden 
Yeah it is the awesome version
Is Limelight there installed by default for that?
I don't think so.

Comment: Yes I think all those plug-ins are supposedly installed by default. If you run `:Limelight` or `:Limelight` does it give you any errors at all?

Comment: @filbranden
Yes.
Something like there's no package / plugin named Limelight :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm on macOS 12.6 for M1, Vim 9.0, and amix/vimrc commit 950b470eb9aa555b7b8a89ba294ce9fc8f7a56e6.

I got it working with GitHub CLI with the following steps:

1. Change to the directory where your own plug-ins should be installed:

```
cd ~/.vim_runtime/my_plugins
```

2. Clone the Limelight repository hosted on GitHub

```
gh repo clone junegunn/limelight.vim
```

3. In VIM, turn on Limelight with:

```
:Limelight [hit return]
```

You should see something like this effect:
[Vim screenshot with Limelight turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpMRy.png)

Source: https://github.com/amix/vimrc#how-to-include-your-own-stuff